# My First Program in C

Tags: c

Ok so I'm making a little program for twitter, basically what you do is type in how many followers you have and you will get a reply.

My problem is when you type in your amount of followers you only get the first reply for <50

Here's the code (also at http://pastie.org/1668357):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int followers;

int main() {


  {
  int followers;

  printf( "Please Enter How Many Twitter Followers You Have...\n" );
  scanf ( "%d" , &followers );
  getchar ();
}
  if ( followers > 50 ) {
   printf ("You may be new to Twitter or rarely use it, try tweeting about more topics.\n" );
   getchar ();

}

  else if ( followers < 100 ) {
   printf ("Reply: Not bad but keep Tweeting.\n" );
   getchar ();
}

  else if ( followers < 200 ) {
   printf ("Reply: People must be interested in your stuff, keep tweeting.\n" );
   getchar();
}

  else if ( followers < 500 ) {
   printf("Reply: Great, you must like Tweeting and other people must like your Tweets, Good job!\n" );
   getchar();
}

  else if ( followers < 1000 ) {
   printf ("Reply: Wow, that's a lot, send some to me @Cian_W\n" );
   getchar();
}

  else if ( followers < 1000000 ) {
   printf ("Reply: Jeez, are you famous? I'd say you like Tweeting\n" );
   getchar();
}

  else if ( followers != 1000000 ) {
   printf ("Reply: Holy crap, are you a celeb? Many people must like you.\n" );
   getchar();

}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks
Cian

Answer (score 4):

You've typed what was apparently supposed to be: "if (followers < 50)" as "if (followers > 50)". Lines 8, 9, and 14 should also be deleted.

Edit: Since question now includes code (without line numbers), the parts that should be deleted are in the following:

```
{
    int followers;

    printf( "Please Enter How Many Twitter Followers You Have...\n" );
    scanf ( "%d" , &followers );
    getchar ();
}
```

You want to get rid of the `{` and `}`. You also want to get rid of one of the two places that `followers` is defined, like: `int followers;`

I had originally said that the one inside main should be deleted, but in reality it would probably be better to delete the global instead. It'll work either way -- the point is to assure that the `followers` you read from the user also gets used in the `if` statements. For a program this tiny, the difference between using a local and a global variable doesn't matter much, but for the long-term, it would be better to learn to avoid globals.

Comment: He didn't provide line numbers in the actual question (just the pastebin).  Can you quote which lines should be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Remove line 9 - You have two **different** variables both called `followers` - And change line 15 to `< 50`

The last if should be `else if ( followers >= 1000000 )` - `>=` not `!=`

Comment: unconditional else would be better at end, avoids duplicating the biggest number which is a recipe for bugs under maintenance.

Comment: @David: Yep - wanted to point out the difference between >= and != and this was quicker than explaining :P

Comment: @cian: They're mostly the same - You have 3 different issues, the duplicate "followers", the `>50` that should be `<50` and the `!=` that should be `>=` - The rest of the logic is good.

Comment: fixed the <50 the != was something i was testing out earlier forgot to change it back

Comment: Have you also removed the extra "followers" variable?

Comment: yep so do i need to start with the bigger numbers?

Comment: @cian: no, that's pointless. Your program structure is fine and it should work nicely if you fix the 3 flaws we've pointed out.

Comment: Then you've changed too much - what does your code look like now?

Comment: @cian: In that paste you have an extra `}` on line 13, and a `<` on line 45 which should be `>=`

Comment: That paste is correct - and it works fine here. What errors do you get?

Comment: expected identifier or '(' before 'else'

Comment: Where? As said, the last paste you showed me compiles without errors here - are you sure you compile exactly what you pasted?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `followers` variable declared both as a global variable, and one within an inner block inside `main()`. When you call `scanf()` you are likely writing to the `followers` that belongs to the innermost scope. It then goes out of scope once you hit that closing brace. Try getting rid of the global followers count, and get rid of the braces around the call to `scanf()`. You also need to fix the logic in your first `if` statement so the comparison goes the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You should check form opposite diretion.

```
if( x > 1000000)
{
}
else if(x > 10000)
{
}
else if(x > 50 )
{
}
```

Or you should match exact interval

```
if(x<50)
{
}
else if((x>=50) && (x<1000))
{
}
else if((x>=1000) && (x<2000))
{
}
```

Comment: -1: This is incorrect. Your second alternative will match everything >50 in the first if.

Comment: I fixed the answerer's errors. There was also a problem where entering 1000 exactly would do nothing.